# export neo4j data to svg file similar to neo4j browser graph - using neo4j gem

Tags: neo4j, ruby-on-rails-5, neo4jrb

Is there a way to export the neo4j data to svg output like the one that appears on the neo4j browser so we can use it inside our application.

This question is with respect to neo4j gem in rails and anyother suggestions are also welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the Neo4j browser application builds its own user interface (including SVG's) using the standard query data from the Neo4j javascript driver. The Neo4j database doesn't contain a build in way to export information as SVG. Nor should it. SVG graphics are a business decision. The way you'd like to visualize graph data in your app is unlikely to be the same way I want to visualize graph data. You'll need to build this functionality yourself.

[Neo4j has an article on graph visualization which may help you implement this.](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/) I believe the Neo4j browser app makes use of the very popular (and open source) [D3.js data visualization library](https://d3js.org/) for building its graph visualizations / SVGs.

https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/